# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: java, string, exception

I am getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the following code. Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:694)
at Reflector.readConfig(Reflector.java:103)
at Reflector.run(Reflector.java:48)
at Reflector.main(Reflector.java:419)
```

Here is code

```
public int readConfig() {
    // validate the contents of the config file
    BufferedReader input=null;
    String name=null; 
    String value=null; 
    String inputLine=null;
    dest=new Hashtable();

    // open and read the config file
    try {
      input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reflector.conf"));
      inputLine=input.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Error reading reflector.conf.");
      return(-1);
    }
    // loop until entire config file is read
    while (inputLine != null) {
      // skip comments:
      if (inputLine.charAt(0) != '#') {
        // extract a name/value pair, and branch
        // based on the name:
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = 
                            new StringTokenizer(inputLine,"="); 
        name = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
        value = tokenizer.nextToken(); 

        if (name == null) {
          System.out.println("no name"); 
          continue;
        } else if (name.equals(MODE)) {
          if (setMode(value) != 0) {
            System.err.println("Error setting mode to " + value);
            return(-1);
          } 

          }
        } else {
          System.err.println("Skipping invalid config file value: " 
                             + name);
        }
      }
      // read next line in the config file
      try {
        inputLine=input.readLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error reading reflector.conf.");
        return(-1);
      }
    }

    // close the config file
    try {
      input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Error closing reflector.conf.");
      return(-1);
    }

    // validate that the combined contents of the config file
    // make sense
    if (! isConfigValid()) {
      System.err.println("Configuration file is not complete.");
      return(-1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an empty line somewhere in the config file and thus the check `if(inputLine.charAt(0) != '#')` throws the exception. Keep in mind `readLine()` does not read the end of line character.

To fix the problem add explicit check to skip empty lines. Easiest fix is to do something like:

```
if (!inputLine.isEmpty() && inputLine.charAt(0) != '#') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here:

```
inputLine.charAt(0)
```

You refer to first element and don't check wheter string has at least one. You should check before wheter this string is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (inputLine.charAt(0) != '#') {
```

You are trying to compare the character at `0` index, but the variable `inputLine` may be having an empty string `""`,

so you also need to check this condition `inputLine.length() != 0`